# How to include a C++ header file on linux in the following case?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a source repository having A, B , C and D sub-repositories. Each A, B, C and D has its own "include" directory where compiler tries to look for header files. I want to include a header file from A into C. I tried copying absolute path but the header itself has some relative path includes which would work only in C directory, as they are not in include directory of B. What is a clean way to include a header file from some other directory in this case?

I am using g++ compiler.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you are using, but there surely is a way to tell it where your include file reside when compiling, for example `-I` in g++

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler to search headers in each of `{A,B,C,D}/include` directories. Then, include file with a path relative to any of the include directories.

> on linux

Then you probably can find the manual of your compiler with the `man` command. The manual will describe how to specify include directories.

Answer (score 0):

With `GCC` you add the paths to the include directories using the `-I` option:

```
g++ -IA/include -IB/include -IC/include -ID/include` -o myprogram myprogram.cpp
```